# Execute initially and via function call

Tags: javascript

What is the best way wrap some code so I can call it with `foo();` and have it execute when the javascript is loaded ?

I want to have foo executed whenever the javascript is loaded and have the ability to call foo  with foo();

Comment: Please clarify your post; what would be calling `foo(bar)` ... what is `foo`, what is `bar`, etc.

Comment: `window.onload = function(){ foo(bar); };`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: Execute at startup of script + execute whenever I need when I use foo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the function assignment in a function wrapper and pass parameters to it.

```
(test = function(a) {
    return a + 7;
})(6); // returns 13

test(2); // returns 9
```

[demo using console.log](http://jsfiddle.net/NtM5R/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the question, but if you want `foo` to run at the start of your script, then just call `foo` at the start of your script.

```
<script>
function foo(bar){
    console.log(bar);
}

foo(8); // call at start of script

// more code

foo(9); // call later in script
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use Joseph's version rather than yours for my case?

Comment: @amiawizard: They are just 2 ways to do the same thing.  Joseph's version is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Rocket I like that... syntactic sugar. XD